# Pattern analogy (2x4 binary)

Tags: pattern

Really struggling with this one, hope you guys can crack it.

```
-OO-   is to  O---
-O--          O--O

as  

----  is to ? O-OO   O---   O--O   OOO-   ---O   O--O
OOO-          ----   O--O   O---   ----   O--O   ---O

               A      B      C      D      E      F
```

(Transposed from https://www.iqutest.com/logical-test-analogies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **A**

Because:

> Swap the 2nd column and the 3rd column,
>
> ```
>  -OO-    -OO- (top one)
>  -O-- -> --O-
>
>  ----    ---- (bottom one)
>  OOO- -> OOO-
> ```
>
> Swap the first to second column and the third to fourth column,
>
> ```
>  -OO-    O--O
>  --O- -> O---
>
>  ----    ----
>  OOO- -> O-OO
> ```
>
> Swap the first row and last row.
>
> ```
>  O--O    O---
>  O--- -> O--O
>
>  ----    O-OO
>  O-OO -> ----
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> If '-' = '1', and the operations on each nibble are invert (xor 0xF) and increment,
>  then the answer would be (D).